# django: how to update models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want the update a model in django
this is a model in models.py:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    CATEGOTY = (
        ('programming', 'programming'),
        ('other', 'other')
    )

    title    = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    content  = models.TextField(null=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGOTY, null=False)
    creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author   = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

for example i want to add slug in this model like this:

```py
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=False)
```

but when i display py manage.py makemigrations; this is shown to me:

```
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

what should I enter if I select option 1?
if i type `datetime.date.today()` It gives me an error that says:
`TypeError: function missing required argument 'year' (pos 1)`

Comment: It makes no sense to add `datetime.date.today()` as a value for a slugfield.

Comment: Can you share the *full* traceback of the error together with the migration file it created?

Comment: it worked i set the default value for slug. thanks for your comment

Comment: it will probably be better if you add a data migration to slugify all the objects. In order to do that, can you share the migration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a mandatory field when the table is not empty, you need to provide the system with information to populate the new field.
For this, you have 2 choices:

- define a rule for a default value
- choose option 2 and, for each row, you will be asked to enter a value

For option 1, maybe you should use slugify() function (from django.utils.text module)

What I do sometimes is add the rule in the model's definitioon, to ensure existing rows will be updated, then I remove the constraints and manage values by the application.

Answer (score 0):

> You can delete your previous migrations then try to migrate again I think it will do the work. but the problem is it will delete all the records.